# Sumar diccionario con lista

Tags: python-3.x, lista, funciones, diccionarios

Tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
ingredientes = {'Tomate': '5', 'Lechuga': '2', 'Hamburguesa': '10', 'Carne': '1', 'Espárragos': '8', 'Pan': '10', 'Papa': '5', 'Cebolla': '12'}
```

La idea es reponer los ingredientes mediante un input donde ingreses los nombres de los ingredientes.

```
lista_input = REPONER Carne Papa Cebolla Espárragos Carne Pan Cebolla
```

Luego se deben agregar en stock los ingredientes del input, para sumarlos al diccionario e ir actualizando los stock, con la instrucción al inicio del input (lista_input[0]) "REPONER".

Al hacer un print debe quedar así:

```
ingredientes = {'Tomate': '5', 'Lechuga': '2', 'Hamburguesa': '10', 'Carne': '3', 'Espárragos': '9', 'Pan': '11', 'Papa': '6', 'Cebolla': '14'}
```

Tengo en mente trabajar con listas para realizar las sumas, pero me complica transformar los string a int. En el diccionario transformo a lista (no sé si será valido) las claves o valores mediante la función .values() ó .keys() pero al imprimir aparece dic_values():

```
dict_values(['5', '2', '10', '1', '8', '10', '5', '12'])
```

Será mejor hacer una función para transformar string a int?
No sé si sumar las claves o valores del diccionario ingredientes con la lista input, que será más sensato?

Comment: Disculpa no entendí muy bien lo que quieres hacer. Que rol cumple el diccionario `ingredientes` y como quieres armar la variable `stock`?

Comment: OK y que le quieres hacer a ese diccionario?

Comment: @Christian el diccionario ingredientes es la base de datos de los `ingredientes`, lo ingreso mediante un .txt que lo transforme a diccionario. Puedo armar la variable `stock` con una función, no se si será mas fácil con listas...

Comment: `stock` contiene los datos del input o el diccionario actualizado de `ingredientes`??

Comment: @Christian diccionario actualizado de `ingredientes`

Comment: mira mi respuesta y avísame si es lo que quieres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución que toma el texto `lista_input` y actualiza el diccionario de `ingredientes`.

```
for ing in lista_input.split()[1:]:
    ingredientes[ing] = str(1 + int(ingredientes[ing]))
```

Primero se usa `split` para convertir el texto `lista_input` en una lista. De esa lista descartamos el primer elemento e iteramos sobre el resto (eso hace `[1:]`).

En cada iteración recuperados el valor asociado al ingrediente en particular. Como está en formato string, lo convierto a entero con `int` y le sumo 1 para actualizar la existencia.

Uso luego `str` para convertir el valor entero a string y actualizar `ingredientes`, manteniendo el tipo de datos del OP.

#### Demo

```
ingredientes = {'Tomate': '5', 'Lechuga': '2', 'Hamburguesa': '10', 'Carne': '1', 'Espárragos': '8', 'Pan': '10', 'Papa': '5', 'Cebolla': '12'}
lista_input = "REPONER Carne Papa Cebolla Espárragos Carne Pan Cebolla"
print(f"Antes: {ingredientes}")
print(lista_input)
for ing in lista_input.split()[1:]:
    ingredientes[ing] = str(1 + int(ingredientes[ing]))
print(f"Después: {ingredientes}")
```

produce

```
Antes: {'Tomate': '5', 'Lechuga': '2', 'Hamburguesa': '10', 'Carne': '1', 'Espárragos': '8', 'Pan': '10', 'Papa': '5', 'Cebolla': '12'}
REPONER Carne Papa Cebolla Espárragos Carne Pan Cebolla
Después: {'Tomate': '5', 'Lechuga': '2', 'Hamburguesa': '10', 'Carne': '3', 'Espárragos': '9', 'Pan': '11', 'Papa': '6', 'Cebolla': '14'}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Como podría generar una función genérica para esta instrucción?

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que tu diccionario `ingredientes` tenga como valor un dato de tipo entero, así se podría facilitar el trabajo.

Yo no veo la necesidad de convertir en una lista de números los datos de entrada, podemos ir sumando `1` al valor cuya clave coincida con el valor ingresado.

Otra cosa es que el `dict_values` es un tipo de dato, el cual también es iterable, por lo que podrías iterarlo sin problema alguno, pero si te molesta o quieres usar todos los métodos de las listas puedes convertirlo a una usando la función `list()`, quedando así `list(ingredientes.values())`.

Como dije una forma es ir sumando 1 por cada vez que el ingrediente aparezca en el input, para eso primero tendremos que separar los valores usando `split()` y lueo iterar.

```py
ingredientes = {'Tomate': '5', 'Lechuga': '2', 'Hamburguesa': '10', 'Carne': '1', 'Espárragos': '8', 'Pan': '10', 'Papa': '5', 'Cebolla': '12'}

lista_input = "REPONER Carne Papa Cebolla Espárragos Carne Pan Cebolla"

#obtenemos los ingredientes
reponer_ingredientes = lista_input.split()[1:] #omitimos la palabra reponer
#sumamos al diccionario ingredientes
for ing in reponer_ingredientes:
    ingredientes[ing]= int(ingredientes[ing])+1 #convertimos a entero y sumamos 1

print(ingredientes)
```

**salida**

```
{'Carne': 3,
 'Cebolla': 14,
 'Espárragos': 9,
 'Hamburguesa': '10',
 'Lechuga': '2',
 'Pan': 11,
 'Papa': 6,
 'Tomate': '5'}
```

Entonces como lo que quieres es que la variable `stock` sea este diccionario actualizado simplemente podemos realizar una **copia** con el método `copy()`

```py
stock = ingredientes.copy()
```

No hagas `stock = ingredientes` pues esto solo causará problemas, no voy a explicar eso por que no es el tema de la pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la clase [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) que te devuelve la cantidad de veces que una `key` aparece en un diccionario.

```
from collections import Counter

ingredientes = {'Tomate': '5', 'Lechuga': '2', 'Hamburguesa': '10', 'Carne': '1', 'Espárragos': '8', 'Pan': '10', 'Papa': '5', 'Cebolla': '12'}
# Aca volvemos entero el value del diccionario "ingredientes", antes de transformarlo a Counter
# para mas adelante poder hacer la suma.
ingredientes = Counter({key: int(value) for key,value in ingredientes.items()}) 

lista_input = "REPONER Carne Papa Cebolla Espárragos Carne Pan Cebolla"

# Armamos un Counter con el nuevo listado de productos recibidos
lista_nuevos_ingredientes = lista_input.split(" ")[1:]
nuevos_ingredientes = Counter(lista_nuevos_ingredientes) 

# Actualizamos el diccionario original "ingredientes" con los nuevos ingredientes 
# y lo convertimos en un dictionary nativo de python, si no le colocas el dict, 
# entonces retornaras un objecto Counter({'Tomate': 5, ... }).
ingredientes = dict(ingredientes + nuevos_ingredientes)
print(ingredientes)
```

Output:

```
{'Tomate': 5, 'Lechuga': 2, 'Hamburguesa': 10, 'Carne': 3, 'Espárragos': 9, 'Pan': 11, 'Papa': 6, 'Cebolla': 14}
```